# How to deal with iOS UNNotificationCategory when passing dynamic action titles from backend

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter, actionable-notification

I'm using actionable notifications. Following data coming from backend :

1. notificationId (String)
2. notification title, body
3. two dynamic titles to show action buttons

I'm registering actions against the notificationId like this :

```
  let notificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory (
        identifier : notificationId,
        actions : [actionPositive, actionNegative],
        intentIdentifiers : [],
        options : []
    )
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current ()
    .setNotificationCategories ([notificationCategory])
```

How to deal with multiple notificationCatagories because **setNotificationCategories()** unregisters all existing catagories to register the new ones(i.e. overriding by new ones).

I'm facing problems to show notifications with diffrent dynamic actions. There is not a single blog/code I found to do this.

Comment: I've solved this. If you're also facing it, tell me